# Save array of Days in Swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift5, saving-data

So i have created a class for a Day and for a Drink. and I'm trying to track how much you drink in a day, but I'm struggling with saving multiple days. I'm currently managing to save the current day(with the amount drunk that day) but i don't know how to save more than one day.

I want to save an array of type Day with all the days. how can i do this?

This is my Day class:

```
public class Day: NSObject {
var date: Date
var goalAmount: Drink
var consumedAmount: Drink

func saveDay() {
    let formatting = DateFormatter()
    formatting.dateFormat = "EEEE - dd/mm/yy"
    UserDefaults.standard.set(formatting.string(from: date), forKey: "date")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(goalAmount.amountOfDrink, forKey: "goal")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(consumedAmount.amountOfDrink, forKey: "consumed")
}

func loadDay() {
    let rawDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "date") as? String ?? ""
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE - dd/mm/yy"
    date = formatter.date(from: rawDate)!
    goalAmount.amountOfDrink = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "goal")
    consumedAmount.amountOfDrink = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "consumed")
}
}
```

This is my Drink class:

```
class Drink: NSObject {
   var typeOfDrink: String
   var amountOfDrink: Float

}
```

i am calling saveDay() when there are any changes made to the day, and then loadDay() when the app opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be is to store the object of the class in userDefaults instead of storing particular properties of that class. And use `[Date]` instead of `Date`  to  save multiple days

For this first, you have **Serialize** the object to store in userDefaults and **Deserialize** to fetch the data from userDefaults.

```
import Foundation

class Day: Codable {

    var date = Date()
    var goalAmount: Drink
    var consumedAmount: Drink

    init(date: Date, goalAmount: Drink,consumedAmount: Drink ) {
        self.date = date
        self.goalAmount = goalAmount
        self.consumedAmount = consumedAmount

    }


  static func saveDay(_ day : [Day]) {
        do {
            let object = try JSONEncoder().encode(day)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(object, forKey: "days")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }

  static func loadDay() {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if  let object = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "days") as? Data {
            do {
                let days = try decoder.decode([Day].self, from: object)

                for day in days {
                    print("Date - ", day.date)
                    print("Goal Amount - ", day.goalAmount)
                    print("Consumed Amount - ",day.consumedAmount)
                    print("----------------------------------------------")
                }


            } catch {
                print(error)
            }


        } else {
            print("unable to fetch the data from day key in user defaults")
        }
    }
}


class Drink: Codable {
    var typeOfDrink: String
    var amountOfDrink: Float

    init(typeOfDrink: String,amountOfDrink: Float ) {
        self.typeOfDrink = typeOfDrink
        self.amountOfDrink = amountOfDrink
    }

}
```

Use `saveAndGet()` method to store and fetch details from userDefaults

```
func saveAndGet() {
 // use any formats to format the dates
        let date = Date()
        let goalAmount = Drink(typeOfDrink: "Water", amountOfDrink: 5.0)
        let consumedAmount = Drink(typeOfDrink: "Water", amountOfDrink: 3.0)

        let day1 = Day(date: date, goalAmount: goalAmount, consumedAmount: consumedAmount)
        let day2 = Day(date: date, goalAmount: goalAmount, consumedAmount: consumedAmount)
        let day3 = Day(date: date, goalAmount: goalAmount, consumedAmount: consumedAmount)
        let day4 = Day(date: date, goalAmount: goalAmount, consumedAmount: consumedAmount)

        let days = [day1, day2, day3, day4]
        Day.saveDay(days)

        Day.loadDay()
    }
```

Comment: when i try to implement this i get: Type 'Day' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' and Type 'Day' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'. i don't understand how to implement those

Comment: Have you added any other custom property in Day class?  if yes then every class or struct should implement the codable protocol.

Comment: It worked after i cleaned the build, but how should i use this? i assume the saveAndGet() function is supposed to be in the viewController, and then call for that when i want to save or get the date. Won't this just use the same values for the drinks on all the dates?

Comment: I want to save an array of type Day, not just the dates.

Comment: I have updated my Solution to store multiple Day and Yes saveAndGet() function is supposed to be in the viewController and call when you want to save and get the data from userDefaults simultaneously.

If you only want to save data in userDefaults use Day.saveDay(_ day: [Day]) and
for fetching data use Day.loadData() method

Comment: After a bit of tinkering whit the code it's working with the rest of my code. thank you for your help

Comment: You're Welcome 

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to create array of object for this :

```
goalAmount = [Drink]()
var date = [Date]()
```

and append with each new element.
you can also add date variable inside your drink class.

2) you can also create array of dictionary:

```
var userData = [String : Any]()
```

key will be you date and Any contain related to drink data in Any you can store Anything.

Comment: I don't see how i would implement that though.

Comment: could you explain how to add that implementation?

Comment: create a class like below

class Drink: NSObject {
   var typeOfDrink: String
   var amountOfDrink: Float
   var date = [Date] ()

init(date: [Date], typeOfDrink: String,amountOfDrink: Float ){
        self.date = date
        self.typeOfDrink = typeOfDrink
        self.amountOfDrink = amountOfDrink
}

 use class object where you want  like in your Day class
}